# Печать штрих кодов на принтере этикеток

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу написать программу, которая будет генерировать штрихкоды из списка серийных номеров, которые будет загружать пользователь, с последующей возможностью печатать получившиеся штрихкоды на принтере ***этикеток***. Написал код, где программа принимает данные от пользователя, генерирует штрихкоды, и сохраняет каждый штрихкод(по отдельности) в папку в формате SVG.

Вопрос -  как должен выглядеть последующий этап программы, чтобы  принтер этикеток обращался к этим файлам( или к файлу, где сгруппированы все штрихкоды)  и выводил один за одним на печать все штрихкоды на принтер этикеток -( условие что одна этикетка - один штрих код).
Помогите, плиз, своими соображениями, или литературой по данной теме, или примерами кода.

```
def butload():
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename(
        filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")]
    )
    if not filepath:
        return
    text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    with open(filepath, "r") as input_file:
        text = input_file.read()
        text_box.insert(tk.END, text)
        text_box.configure(state="disabled")
    a = text

    for b in a.split():
        if not os.path.isdir ('barcode'):
            os.mkdir('barcode')
        code = barcode.get('code128', b)
        filename = code.save('barcode\\'+b)
    btn3.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от принтера и в каком режиме он подключен. Если он подключен без драйвера системы печати, то сначала svg переводим в

```
    buff = BytesIO()
    cairosvg.svg2png(dpi=203, bytestring=svgdata, write_to=buff)
    buff.seek(0)
    img = Image.open(buff)
    printer.image(img)
```

где принтер это экземпляр `escpos.printer.Usb` или подобный

```
    import escpos.printer
    printer = escpos.printer.Usb(0x04b8, 0x0202, 0, profile="TM-T88III")
```

многие модели умеют печатать штрихкоды без перевода в картинку, но практика печати картинкой ещё сохраняется

```
    printer.barcode('1324354657687', 'EAN13', 64, 2, '', '')
```

https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos

Если принтер установлен в систему как принтер, то нужно правильно выставить параметры страницы и печатать как на обычном принтере.